# How to set size of JScrollPane according to JFrame size?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have been working on a `JFrame`, which contains a panel of multiple components. However, the frame cannot accommodate all components due to its size. I wish to use a scrollable frame, and came across a link where `JScrollPane` use is suggested. However, when the frame is resized, the scroll pane container does not take up the size of the resized frame.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Add the ScrollPane to the JFrame. `add(new JScrollPane(something));`

Comment: *"I use a Frame with FlowLayout"* ..why? Are there components (outside the scroll pane) that are also in the frame? Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. Just show the scroll pane as a single component. Don't worry about trying to show all the components inside it.

Comment: Yeah you are right, i just realised that i could change the layout of my JFrame. Thank you very much @AndrewThompson.

Answer (score 5):

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the `CENTER` of the BorderLayout the component will take all the available space of the frame.

So the basic logic is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Infact, I use a Frame with FlowLayout. Is there any other way to go about it please?

Comment: @JoeMcHart, glad your problem has been solved by using the default BorderLayout. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Set the frame to use grid layout. Gridlayout makes all of the components in the frame use up the entire size.

```
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
```

Comment: There is no need to change the layout. The default layout is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout the component will take up all the space available to the frame. The BorderLayout is a good starting point for any application because you could also all a panel to the "PAGE_START" of the layout. This is helpful for adding a toolbar. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I haven't done much with Java GUIs, but most of my expierence is with Netbeans GUI builder which uses a form of the absolute layout as its default so I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the tip!